# how can I decrease execution time needed for python code?

Tags: python, python-3.x, arraylist

```
#https://www.codechef.com/problems/GRIDGM
from sys import setrecursionlimit
setrecursionlimit(10**6)
def sol(l,lst):
    sum=0
    for i in range(l[0],l[2]+1):
        for j in range(l[1],l[3]+1):
            #print(lst[i-1][j-1],end="")
            sum += lst[i-1][j-1]
        #print('---')
    #print("sol below")    
    return sum
            
for _ in range(int(input())):
    n,m=map(int, input("enter values of n and m").split())
    lst=[]
    for _ in range(n):
        lst.append(list(map(int,input("enter a row").split())))
        #print(lst)
    #q=int(input())
    
    #dj=[] #it saves x y and a b
    for _ in range(int(input("enter no of queries"))):
        #v=list(map(int,input().split()))
        #print(v)
        #print('sol below')
        print(sol(list(map(int,input("enter cordinates").split())),lst))
```

sample input

```
1
4 4
9 13 5 2
1 11 7 6
3 7 4 1
6 0 7 10
2
2 1 4 2
2 2 4 4
```

output

```
28
53
```

above code took 5.1 sec to execute.
in this question, I have to find sum of elements within given coordinates a,b and x,y
more information about this problem can be found in the link below.
https://www.codechef.com/problems/GRIDGM

Comment: Note, you may pass a string to your inputs calls, like `input("Enter x values: ")` to know where you are

Comment: ok, I will do that

Comment: Also i don't see any recursion, why do you change the limit recursion ?

Comment: It is was my  error ,I was using for it for my previous problem

Comment: It won't affect the code right

Comment: What's the question ? Speeding up the the script or is there anything wrong with the output ?